# AWS S3 .NET SDK: is the connection encrypted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know how to upload an object to S3 using the .NET SDK:

```
        IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecreteKey, enRegion);
        PutObjectRequest putReq = new PutObjectRequest();
        putReq.FilePath = strLocalFilePath;
        putReq.BucketName = strBucketName;
        putReq.Key = strKeyName;
        putReq.ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256;
        PutObjectResponse putResp = client.PutObject(putReq);
```

What I don't know is: is the connection encrypted (SSL)? If not, how to make the connection encrypted? In other words, how to make the data in transit encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS API Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) are available as both HTTP and HTTPS.

The AWS SDKs all connect via HTTPS. Thus, the traffic is encrypted.